# Overriding FosUser Registration Controller symfony 3

Tags: symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle, registration, symfony-3.3

Im trying to override FOSUser RegistrationController. In SF2 I used to copy the controller in my AppBundle\Controller and add bundle inheritance

```
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }

}
```

**In symfony 3 the bundle inheritance is not supported anymore**, and when I do the same as above,  I end up with errors saying that symfony cannot find the services used in this controller (cannot autowire..)

Does anyone has an idea how to override FOSUser in SF3 please ?

Comment: FYI the bundle inheritance is still supported in Symfony 3 (although [it is deprecated](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-deprecated-bundle-inheritance)). It is not supported anymore in Symfony 4.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Even if it is still supported I don't want to use depricated stuff as I'm on a new project that may migrate to SF4 soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
        $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
        $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

        $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
        if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            /*****************************************************
             * Add new functionality (e.g. log the registration) *
             *****************************************************/
            $this->container->get('logger')->info(
                sprintf('New user registration: %s', $user)
            );

            if ($confirmationEnabled) {
                $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
            } else {
                $this->authenticateUser($user);
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
            }

            $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);

            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

[from the official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html)

I'm not truly sure of my answer because i didnt override the FOS User Bundle but the Easy Admin Bundle in sf4. Here's what i did : create a new controller in src/Controller/MyCustomController. Next i extended MyCustomController with the Controller i wanted to overide :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController as BaseAdminController;
class MyCustomController extends BaseAdminController {}
?>
```

I guess you can do the same in sf3 with the FosUserBundle.
Hope i'm right !

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is the documentation for the version 1.3 of FOSUser, I'm using the 2.0 Besides, it says : " The first step to overriding a controller in the bundle is to create a child bundle whose parent is FOSUserBundle " and I'm trying not to use bundle inheritance as it is depricated in SF3 and not supported in SF4

Comment: I'm not truly sure of my answer because i didnt override the FOS User Bundle but the Easy Admin Bundle in sf4. i updated my answer